# convert integer to Days

Tags: sql, casting, db2, converters

I'm looking to convert an integer to Days using a db2 database.  The integers are in this format 20130101 or YYYYMMDD.  I believe you have to write a custom function after converting the integer to a char but I was unsure of how to do the second conversion to DAYS.  I'm looking for a returned format January, 1, 2013 from 20130101.

```
  WITH
/*****************************************************
*** Sample Data  ***
*****************************************************/
 sample_data
( START_DATE , END_DATE ) AS 
(
VALUES
  (20130101, 20131227 ) 
, (20130930, 20131230 ) 
, (20130411, 20130912 )
, (20130410, 20140101 )


)
,

            t2(START_DATE, END_DATE) AS
    ( SELECT    

            CAST(SUBSTR(START_DATE, 1,4) CONCAT '-'
            CONCAT SUBSTR(START_DATE, 5,2) CONCAT '-'
            CONCAT SUBSTR(START_DATE, 7,2) AS CHAR(15)), 
            CAST(SUBSTR(END_DATE, 1,4) CONCAT '-'
            CONCAT SUBSTR(END_DATE, 5,2) CONCAT '-'
            CONCAT SUBSTR(END_DATE, 7,2) AS CHAR(15)) 

    FROM SAMPLE_DATA

    )

    SELECT
                START_DATE,
                END_DATE
    FROM t2
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'convert to DAYS' ?  In DB2 there is a `DAYS()` function that converts a date into an integer representing the number of days since '01/01/0001', but you indicate you want `January 1, 2013`.

Comment: Number of days is a *very* different thing from a number in YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: Date was actually what I was looking for and Ian's answer did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot of casting, but you can use the `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` function:

```
date(timestamp_format(char(start_date),'YYYYMMDD'))
```

Keep in mind that this just gets you a value that is an actual `DATE`, not necessarily in the "pretty" format that you list above.

Comment: Just wanted to add that Ian's conversion can be further simplified, resuting in this: to_date(start_date,''YYYYMMDD''). That's because the int to char conversion is implicit.

Comment: @Ricardo That's a good point, I'm still stuck in the pre-9.7-cast-everything mode.  But technically the proper expression is `date(to_date(start_date,'YYYYMMDD'))` if you want an actual `DATE` instead of a `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
select monthname(to_date(20130101, 'YYYYMMDD')) || ', ' || 
    day(to_date(20130101, 'YYYYMMDD')) || ', ' || 
    year(to_date(20130101, 'YYYYMMDD')) from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

The result is:

```
January, 1, 2013
```

Replace the integer 20130101 by your field name.

If you will be using the conversion in several places, it's probably better to create a function to avoid repeating the field and conversions.

You could also cut a few corners using aritmetics to get year and day, such as this:

```
select monthname(to_date(20130101, 'YYYYMMDD')) || ', ' || 
    mod(20130101, 100) || ', ' || to_char(20130101 / 10000) from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

The result is the same.